# How to remove the Query String and Hash Values from URL Using JSOUP or Coldfusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jsoup

**Here is the example:**

When I parse an HTML page. I am getting duplicate URL values like

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=featured&pageSize=50
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java#comments
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java#comment212

How to avoid this above duplicate values?

I only need this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Answer (score 3):

I created a helper method `processURL()` which accepts a URL and returns a URL containing everything up to either the query marker (`?`) or a hash sign (`#`):

```
String processURL(String theURL) {
    int endPos;
    if (theURL.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        endPos = theURL.indexOf("?");
    } else if (theURL.indexOf("#") > 0) {
        endPos = theURL.indexOf("#");
    } else {
        endPos = theURL.length();
    }

    return theURL.substring(0, endPos);
}

String urlOne = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jav?#sort=featured&pageSize=50";
String urlTwo = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java#comments";

System.out.println(processURL(urlOne));
System.out.println(processURL(urlTwo));
```

**Output:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java
```